# Dynamic props dialog into operator

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, operator

good day. I want to change the props **into operators dialog**. something like this:
[image]

[image]

if I select the option A....then show for example some buttons
[image]

but if I select option B then show for example some slider or text entry
[image]

some code that Im test is:

```
class PUPA_OT_FitArmature(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.test"
    bl_label = "test"
    bl_category = "test"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

   
    options = [
            ("Select option","Select option","Select option"),
            ("Option A", "Option A", "Option A"),
            ("Option B", "Option B", "Option B")
    ]
    CollectionName:  EnumProperty( 
        items =options,     
        name="Collections"
    )

    test_checkbox : bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="test_checkbox ",
        description="test_checkbox", 
        default= False
    )

    slider : bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="slider",
        description="allow change some size", 
        default= 0.1,
        min =0.01,
        max = 2
    )

    def testM(self, context):

        print("test")



    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
       return context

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    def execute(self, context):
        D = bpy.data
        C = bpy.context

        self.testM(C)


        return {'FINISHED'}
```

but I can not use `if else` within the property definition because the register is in process... then something like this don't work
[image]

some ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't doing logic operation when defining class attribute in python. To customize the layout of redo panel—the dialog box that usually came out when you call operator—is using `draw` method.

Say you want to certain property is hidden when you change another property, first you define property to toggle the change, with `EnumProperty`

```py
options: EnumProperty(
        name="Options",
        default=0,
        items = [
            # identifier    name       description   number
            ('option_a', "Option A", "Active Button", 0),
            ('option_b', "Option B", "Show a Slider", 1)]
        )
```

`items` is a sequence of enum items, list of tuples. You can read the [documentation here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty). Then you define the layout in method `draw`.

```py
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.prop(self, "options")

    if self.options == "option_a":
        layout.prop(self, "prop_A")
    elif self.options == "option_b":
        layout.prop(self, "prop_B")
    else:
        ...
```

Make sure to draw the layout for enum property as well, unless it will not show you anything on the panel. When you define `draw`, blender will not automatically draw the layout for all defined properties so you have to do it manually.

Complete code:

```py
import bpy

from bpy.props import EnumProperty, BoolProperty, FloatProperty

class PUPA_OT_FitArmature(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.fit_armature"
    bl_label = "Fit Armature"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
   
    options: EnumProperty(
        name="Options",
        default=0,
        items = [
            ('option_a', "Option A", "Active Button", 0),
            ('option_b', "Option B", "Show a Slider", 1)]
        )

    test_checkbox: BoolProperty(
        name="Test Checkbox ",
        description="Test Checkbox", 
        default= False
    )

    slider: FloatProperty(
        name="Slider",
        description="Allow Change Some Size", 
        default= 0.1,
        min =0.01,
        max = 2
    )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.prop(self, "options")

        if self.options == "option_a":
            layout.prop(self, "test_checkbox")
        elif self.options == "option_b":
            layout.prop(self, "slider")

    def testM(self, context):
        print("test")

    def execute(self, context):
        self.testM(bpy.context)
        
        return {"FINISHED"}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(PUPA_OT_FitArmature)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PUPA_OT_FitArmature)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Result:

[image: Operation]